# Python Panel Dashboard - Multi-Page app not updating as expected

Tags: python, dashboard, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I want a Python Panel app which shows different page content based on a radio button selection in the sidebar.

There's some example code for doing exactly this in the way I want, shown as "Option 3" here:
https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/multi-page-app-documentation/3108/3?u=maxpower

Code below:

````
import panel as pn

pn.extension(sizing_mode="stretch_width")

pages = {
    "Page 1": pn.Column("# Page 1", "...bla bla bla"),
    "Page 2": pn.Column("# Page 2", "...more bla"),
}


def show(page):
    return pages[page]


starting_page = pn.state.session_args.get("page", [b"Page 1"])[0].decode()
page = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    value=starting_page,
    options=list(pages.keys()),
    name="Page",
    sizing_mode="fixed",
    button_type="success",
)
ishow = pn.bind(show, page=page)
pn.state.location.sync(page, {"value": "page"})

ACCENT_COLOR = "#0072B5"
DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    "site": "Panel Multi Page App",
    "accent_base_color": ACCENT_COLOR,
    "header_background": ACCENT_COLOR,
}
pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title="As Single Page App",
    sidebar=[page],
    main=[ishow],
    **DEFAULT_PARAMS,
).servable()
```import panel as pn

pn.extension(sizing_mode="stretch_width")

pages = {
    "Page 1": pn.Column("# Page 1", "...bla bla bla"),
    "Page 2": pn.Column("# Page 2", "...more bla"),
}


def show(page):
    return pages[page]


starting_page = pn.state.session_args.get("page", [b"Page 1"])[0].decode()
page = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    value=starting_page,
    options=list(pages.keys()),
    name="Page",
    sizing_mode="fixed",
    button_type="success",
)
ishow = pn.bind(show, page=page)
pn.state.location.sync(page, {"value": "page"})

ACCENT_COLOR = "#0072B5"
DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    "site": "Panel Multi Page App",
    "accent_base_color": ACCENT_COLOR,
    "header_background": ACCENT_COLOR,
}
pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title="As Single Page App",
    sidebar=[page],
    main=[ishow],
    **DEFAULT_PARAMS,
).servable()
````

However, it does not quite work as expected, at least not on panel v1.0.0rc6. When I click "Page 2" and then click back to "Page 1", the main content does not switch back as expected. Weirdly, the URL does switch between `...=Page+1` and `...=Page+2` as expected, but not the main content itself.

I've been trying to debug this using panel serve app.py --autoreload, which is a nice workflow, but I still haven't been able to figure out why this isn't working, or a good solution to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given [here](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/further-elaboration-on-multi-page-apps/5093/2?u=maxpower) is exactly what I was looking for, and I've confirmed works as expected in Panel's v1.0.0rc6:

```
import panel as pn
from panel.template import FastListTemplate

pn.extension()

# Define pages as classes
class Page1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = pn.Column("# Page 1", "This is the content of page 1.")

    def view(self):
        return self.content


class Page2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = pn.Column("# Page 2", "This is the content of page 2.")

    def view(self):
        return self.content

# Instantiate pages and add them to the pages dictionary
pages = {
    "Page 1": Page1(),
    "Page 2": Page2(),
}

# Function to show the selected page
def show_page(page_instance):
    main_area.clear()
    main_area.append(page_instance.view())

# Define buttons to navigate between pages
page1_button = pn.widgets.Button(name="Page 1", button_type="primary")
page2_button = pn.widgets.Button(name="Page 2", button_type="primary")

# Set up button click callbacks
page1_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 1"]))
page2_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 2"]))

# Create the sidebar
sidebar = pn.Column(page1_button, page2_button)

# Create the main area and display the first page
main_area = pn.Column(pages["Page 1"].view())

# Create the Material Template and set the sidebar and main area
template = FastListTemplate(
    title="Multi-Page App",
    sidebar=[sidebar],
    main=[main_area],
)

# Serve the Panel app
template.servable()
```