# Panel dashboard: links in multipage with loop not correct

Tags: python, panel-pyviz

I am trying to create a multipage dashboard with `panel`.

My question is based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222741/5013084):

```py
import panel as pn
from panel.template import FastListTemplate

pn.extension()


class Page1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = pn.Column("# Page 1", "This is the content of page 1.")

    def view(self):
        return self.content


class Page2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = pn.Column("# Page 2", "This is the content of page 2.")

    def view(self):
        return self.content

def show_page(page_instance):
    main_area.clear()
    main_area.append(page_instance.view())


pages = {
    "Page 1": Page1(),
    "Page 2": Page2()
}

page_buttons = {}
for page in pages:
    page_buttons[page] = pn.widgets.Button(name=page, button_type="primary")
    # page_buttons[page].on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages[page]))

page1_button, page2_button = page_buttons.values()

page1_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 1"]))
page2_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 2"]))

sidebar = pn.Column(*page_buttons.values())

main_area = pn.Column(pages["Page 1"].view())

template = FastListTemplate(
    title="Multi-Page App",
    sidebar=[sidebar],
    main=[main_area],
)

template.servable()
```

If I am uncommenting this line in the `for` loop

```py
page_buttons[page].on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages[page]))
```

and remove (or comment as below) the two `on_click` statements

```py
# page1_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 1"]))
# page2_button.on_click(lambda event: show_page(pages["Page 2"]))
```

both links on the sidebar point to page 2.

Can somebody explain to me why this is the case and how I can fix this issue?

Note: Of course, for two pages, a for loop is not needed, however in my case, my app will include a few more pages, and I would like to make the code more robust (i.e. to avoid forgetting to add a page or a click event).

Thank you!

Note: `page1_button, page2_button = page_buttons.values()` is currently only used because my `for` loop does not work as intended right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into one of the *classical* footguns in Python: late binding aka "capture by reference".

By the time your lambda callback is *evaluated* (on click), the `page` variable points at page 2 (loop has ended), and both lambdas capture the *variable*, not its value at time of call.

The operative line should become:

```py
page_buttons[page].on_click(lambda event, saved=page: show_page(pages[saved]))
```

This forces an early binding by storing the *current* value as a default paramater, *while still in the loop context*.

The canonical answer goes into more detail.
[Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension).

Comment: I think it's debatable if this counts as a "duplicate" question. The problem to me is always *recognising* the problem, and the recognition *in this instance* is not a strict duplicate of the canonical answer.

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding that answer. Using the late binding fix leads to a `KeyError`.

Comment: @revan: does the code example I just added help?